# Conditional statement in Node/JavaScript - call stack size exceeded

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express

My script is restarting/sending again `GET` request as long as `music` value is returned in JSON's `type` field.

Expected behaviour: run the GET call as long as it returns `type == 'music'` is achieved but there are runs that end with `Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

How to overcome this?

JSON Structure:

```
{
  activity: "Solve a Rubik's cube",
  type: 'recreational',
  participants: 1,
  price: 0,
  link: '',
  key: '4151544',
  accessibility: 0.1
}
```

Code:

```
//tech: node.js + mongoose
//import components
const https = require('https');
const options = new URL('https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity');

//obtain data using GET
https.get(options, (response) => {
  //console.log('statusCode:', response.statusCode);
  //console.log('headers:', response.headers);

  response.on('data', (data) => {
        //process.stdout.write(data);
        apiResult = JSON.parse(data);
        apiResultType = apiResult.type;
        returnDataOutside(data);
  });
 })

.on('error', (error) => {
  console.error(error);
 });


function returnDataOutside(data){
  apiResultType;

  if (apiResultType == 'music' || apiResultType ==  "relaxation" || apiResultType == "charity") {
    console.log(apiResult);
  } else {
    returnDataOutside(data);
    console.log(apiResult); //Maximum call stack size exceeded
  };
};
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this is throwing an error because what you have is valid code. Once the condition evaluates to false the `do/while` loop ends and undefined is not equal to value of music.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the code that runs in the condition after the `while` keyword has access to the variable declarations `apiResultType` in the `do` block. If I understand your question right, what you'd want to do is declare the variable `apiResultType` right above the loop, and update that variable once you're inside the loop. That way both the do block and the while condition have access to the variable, via closure.

```
//import components
const https = require("https");
const options = new URL("https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity");

//obtain data using GET
//loop till get data where type = 'music'

https
  .get(options, (response) => {
    //console.log('statusCode:', response.statusCode);
    //console.log('headers:', response.headers);

    // declaration happens outside of do block. 
    let apiResultType;
    do {
      response.on("data", (data) => {
        //process.stdout.write(data);
        let apiResult = JSON.parse(data);

        // update the variable here, instead of initializing it. This block
        // has access to the outer blocks' variables
        apiResultType = apiResult.type;
        console.log(apiResult);
      });
    } while (apiResultType == "music"); //error: apiResultType is not defined
  })

  .on("error", (error) => {
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Comment: Ok, I see the thing with variable scope was in wrong palce. However the code works but returns JSON where `type` is different then `music`. I want the loop to run as long as I will get `type == 'music'`